# Global .gitignore with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I tried researching a bit but couldn't find an answer. Is there a way to configure a global .gitignore with Visual Studio? Id rather not add a bunch of developer specific options to the project's .gitignore.

Comment: Well.... in general `.gitignore` is what you would keep as _the gereral rules for ignoring_ in a given project. When I see that I want to skip some files _without_ wanting to add a line to the project's `.gitgnore`, I use `.git/info/exclude` for that, so that no one else is affected and I still get away with my ignored file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take.  The first, if you want to make some project-specific changes is to use `.git/info/exclude`.  That works just like `.gitignore`, but is specific to that repository.

If you want to make more global changes, such as to ignore editor backup files, then you'll want to create a file and set the `core.excludesFile` option to that file's name.  If that file is not set (and you also haven't set the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable), it defaults to `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`.